# Integral Question

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals

$$
\int _{\large{ -\frac { \pi  }{ 2 } } }^{\large{ \frac { \pi  }{ 2 } } }{ \frac { \mathrm{d}x }{ \sin x-2\cos x+3 }  } 
$$

Wolframalpha suggests to evaluate indefinite integral by substituting $u = \tan(\frac { x }{ 2 })$. Is there a more basic way to evaluate this definite integral?

Comment: What's wrong with the WA suggestion? That's the standard thing for trig integrals.

Comment: $\ddot \smile +1\ $Yes, and its called the Weierstrasse (correct spelling is "Weierstraß", as pointed out in the comment below) substitution.

Comment: Weierstraß please, Karl Weierstraß.

Comment: Of course, WA's suggestion does work. My question is "Is there any other way to evaluate this definite integral?"

Comment: Yes, set $z=\exp(ix)$, $\cos(x)=(z+z^{-1})/2$ etc. and apply calculus of residues.

Comment: Something this ugly is probably the perfect place for WA's suggested substitution.

Comment: I edited the question. Is there a more basic way to evaluate the definite integral? Without using $tan(\frac {x} {2})$ and complex numbers :) I am just a MATH101 student and these substitutions has not been shown yet.

Comment: @LutzL: note the interval of integration.  How exactly will you apply the residue theorem?

Comment: So at first it is just complex integration along the half circle from $-i$ to $i$. It might be, I did not check it, that the integral along the imaginary axis from $-i$ to $i$ is easy to determine, then the difference to the half circle would be covered by the residue theorem.

Comment: @LutzL: You end up with the original integral plus an integral over the reciprocal of a quadratic having complex coefficients being equal to the sum of the residues of the poles inside the half disk.  The second integral is in principle doable because it can be broken up into a few logs, but they are complex and messy.  But who knows, maybe the whole thing might not be bad.

Comment: Yes, in the meantime I came to the same conclusion, it would be quite messy. But still, it is possible and it is an alternative approach.

Answer (score 2):

There *is* another way to deal with this, but it's a special-case trick and may never serve you again. But here goes: when you see $$A\sin(x) + B \cos(x),$$ you can rewrite that as 
$$
K \sin(x + c)
$$
for some constants $K$ and $c$. How? Pick
$$
K = \sqrt{A^2 + B^2};
$$
in your case, that gives you $K = \sqrt{5}$. 
Let 
$$
c = \cos^{-1}(A/K).
$$

In your case, you get $c = 1.107...$ radians.

Now check: if $\sin(c)$ has the same sign as $B$, leave $c$ as is; if not, negate $c$.

In your case, $\sin(c) = 0.89...$, so the sign's wrong, and we have to make $c = -1.107...$ radians. But I'm just going to leave it as $-\cos^{-1}(1/\sqrt{5})$, and write it as $c$.

Alternatively, you can let $c  = atan2(A, B)$, assuming you know about the atan2 function.

So now your integrand becomes

$$
\frac{dx}{K\sin(x + c) + 3} \\
= \frac{dx}{\sqrt{5}\sin(x + c) + 3}
$$

You can let $u = x + c$ and $du = dx$ to get
$$
\frac{du}{\sqrt{5}\sin(u) + 3}.
$$
Multiply top and bottom by the "conjugate" to get
$$
\frac{(\sqrt{5}\sin(u) -  3 ) du}{5\sin^2(u) - 9}.
$$
Now write $5 \sin^2 u  - 9 = 5(\sin^2 u - 1) - 4 = -5 \cos^2(u) - 4$, so the integrand becomes
$$
-\frac{(\sqrt{5}\sin(u) -  3 ) du}{5\cos^2(u) + 4} \\
= -\frac{\sqrt{5}\sin(u)du}{5\cos^2(u) + 4} + \frac{3 du}{5\cos^2(u) + 4} 
$$

The first part can be addressed with a substitution $v = \cos u$, which produces a logarithm term.

The second part...well, that's difficult in itself, but only solution is to let $u = \tan^{-1}(x)$. Then $\cos(u) = \dfrac{x}{\sqrt{1 + x^2}}$, so $\cos^2(x) = \dfrac{x^2}{1 + x^2}$, while $du = \frac{1}{1 + x^2} dx$. So the second term becomes

$$
 \frac{3 du}{5\cos^2(u) + 4} \\
= \frac{3}{5\dfrac{x^2}{1 + x^2} + 4} \frac{1}{1 + x^2} dx \\
= \frac{3}{5x^2 + 4(1 + x^2)} dx \\
= \frac{3}{9x^2 + 4} dx \\
= \frac{3/4}{\frac{9}{4}x^2 + 1} dx \\
= \frac{3/4}{(\frac{3}{2}x)^2 + 1} dx
$$
Now letting $z = \frac{3}{2} x$, you've got an arctangent integral, and you should be on your way.

After all that, the $\tan(t/2)$ substitution seems pretty nice, doesn't it?  :)

Key idea: a linear combination of $\sin(ax)$ and $\cos(ax)$ can be rewritten as $K\sin(ax + c)$ for some $K$ and $c$.

Answer (score 2):

@ Hckr, we propose to calculate the full applying WA and then judge you whether to seek another method:

$u=\tan \frac{x}{2}=>\ dx = \frac{2}{u^2+1}\ du$
$$
\int _{\large{ -\frac { \pi  }{ 2 } } }^{\large{ \frac { \pi  }{ 2 } } }{ \frac { \mathrm{d}x }{ \sin x-2\cos x+3 }  }= \int _{-1}^{1}{ \frac {2 \mathrm{d}u }{ 5u^2+2u+1}  }=\frac{2}{5}\int _{-1}^{1}{ \frac { \mathrm{d}u }{ (u+\frac{1}{5})^2+(\frac{2}{5})^2}  }=$$
$$=\frac{2}{5}\cdot(\frac{2}{5})^{-1} \cdot \tan^{-1}\frac{5u+1}{2}|_{-1}^1=\tan^{-1}3-\tan^{-1}(-2)=\tan^{-1}3+\tan^{-1}2= \frac{3}{4}\pi 
$$

Comment: Yes, u = tan(x/2) appears to be the easiest method to evaluate such integrals. Thanks.